# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

i am trying to import scripts from

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-messaging.js");
```

its for firebase cloud messaging (FCM) but idk why angular does not like to import on a ServiceWorker

it imports it (clicked the error URL and got the script) but somehow failed to load?

[image: script loaded and viewed]

[image: laoded]

**error is here:**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-app.js' failed to load.
    at initInSw (http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js:35:1)
    at http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js:56:1
```

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.json",
          "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
        ],
```

**index.html**

```
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

**directory**

[image: file directory]

tried to use fireship's implementation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z27IroVNFLI&t=140s&ab_channel=Fireship but does not work either (same implementation just different firebase version) and i also think theres nothing to do with this

my theory is that i think it really didnt load and the one that i viewed is the console request? (because the filename is (index) in means that it has no filename thus not exist?)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep using a plain-JS service worker file along with >= v9 SDK you need to reformat the file like this:

`public/firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
// v8/namespaced style service worker
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.1.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js')

const firebase_config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config)
firebase.messaging()
```

`importScripts` wont work with v9+ without using the `-compat` library, but note this will lose all benefits of the modular library (it will import everything).

You have to boot your app, and call `firebase.messaging()` for the service worker to start listening.

If you are using the modern Firebase libraries in your app, you don't need to register the service worker - it will find `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and register it automatically.

If you wanted to use the other examples provided in some of these answers, using `import` and the v9 modular syntax, you would need to include the service worker in your app build, as you can't use `import` in a plain JS file which isn't a module.

The solution DEEz used was to avoid the problem by downgrading their library to v8 and continue using the namespaced syntax. This would work of course, but at some point will block the upgrade maintenance.

I thought I'd add this answer, as non of the other answers had a complete "v8" style worker file, just parts mixed in with v9 examples which I found confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following thread helpful at resolving this issue:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5403

There appears to be a compatibility issue introduced around Service Workers broadly and the `importScripts` function. There is a workaround shown in this thread that allows you to use the older style of importing libraries while using the newest (v9) version of Firebase.

Comment: Apologies,I hit submit reflexively. Context has been added!

Comment: Issue still persists as of today, new threads related to it:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6844
and
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7030

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use version 9 you should use code like this

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});

const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
```

Because they have changed the lib script format like ts.

if you still want to use like older versions you can use Compat edition.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
```

And you can still change version code to latest.

Answer (score 1):

Following [these instructions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5732#issuecomment-969453902) helped me, I added `-compat` to the firebase scripts URL

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.2/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js')

// my custom environment file for firebase
importScripts('environment.js')

const app = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
firebase.messaging().onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
   return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, {body: payload.notification.body});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

after solving it for half a day
I figured that it needs an older version of firebase (9.1.0 => 8.10)

so I synced up the `angular.json` firebase version and the service worker version to 8.10 and it worked!

Comment: it would be great if someone explain what breaking changes happened on 9.1.0 that the script failed to load

Comment: check my answer

Comment: The v9 SDKs were a big change in terms of how the libraries were presented as "modular" rather than "namespaced". The functionality was pretty much the same but it was a huge refactor from v8 to allow tree-shaking and so smaller target apps.   https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade and see https://dev.to/chroline/why-the-new-firebase-web-v9-modular-sdk-is-a-game-changer-nph

Answer (score 0):

In **web version-9** You have to do like this

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});

const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
```

Comment: How is "firebase/app" pinned to the proper gstatic script? https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js  Is there an importmap required to go with this?