# Publishing Flutter web app on web server shows blank screen

Tags: flutter, firebase

I need to publish my Flutter web app on a web server folder.

Here you have the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="/freelife/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="capenergy_ns">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Freelife</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>

  const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIz...",
        authDomain: "fre...",
        projectId: "fre...",
        storageBucket: "free...",
        messagingSenderId: "53...",
        appId: "1:538....",
        measurementId: "G-X..."
};
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here you have firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-messaging.js");
firebase.initializeApp({
       apiKey: "AIz...",
        authDomain: "free...",
        projectId: "free...",
        storageBucket: "free...",
        messagingSenderId: "53...",
        appId: "1:53...",
        measurementId: "G-X..."
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    const promiseChain = clients
        .matchAll({
            type: "window",
            includeUncontrolled: true
        })
        .then(windowClients => {
            for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                const windowClient = windowClients[i];
                windowClient.postMessage(payload);
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            return registration.showNotification("New Message");
        });
    return promiseChain;
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    console.log('notification received: ', event)
});
```

The issue is that publishing the created web folder inside build folder in the app, launching the web in the browser shows a blank page.

Lookin the output of the web console debugger, it throws a lot of errors:

[image]

The web app was working fine until I inserted all Firebase dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70868923/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-importscripts-on-workerglobalscope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue changing index.html as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
      If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
      href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

      The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
      it to work correctly.

      For more details:
      * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

      This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
      the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
    -->
    <base href="/webapp/">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="freelife">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

    <title>capenergy_ns</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
    <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script type="module">


  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIza...",
    authDomain: "fre...",
    projectId: "fre...",
    storageBucket: "free...",
    messagingSenderId: "538...",
    appId: "1:...",
    measurementId: "G-..."
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And then on main.dart, I have updated the piece of code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(

      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "AIza....",
          appId: "1:5389...",
          messagingSenderId: "...",
          projectId: "...")
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

try deleting [base href="/freelife/"] from the index.html file
It should stay like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
    <!--<base href="/freelife/"> -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="capenergy_ns">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Freelife</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script>

  const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIz...",
        authDomain: "fre...",
        projectId: "fre...",
        storageBucket: "free...",
        messagingSenderId: "53...",
        appId: "1:538....",
        measurementId: "G-X..."
};
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("firebase-messaging-sw.js");
      });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: removing that line doesn't solve the issue